# RSS feeds of conference proceedings from dblp?

Tags: conference, proceedings

I am looking for a way to get RSS updates (to consume through Feedly) of proceedings of some major conferences in my area (computer security). I thought I could get them from dblp directly, since they already indicize everything, however I can't seem to find a way.

For the moment I have seen only this [old project](http://services.ceon.pl/dblpfeeds/), which now seems abandoned, and the generic dblp feed of all conferences. This last one, however, is kind of too generic and  not really what I was looking for.

Does anyone know if there is any way of getting specific conference proceedings RSS feeds (posssibly through dblp but that's not mandatory)?

Comment: Have you considered using the generic DBLP stream in combination with a filter in Feedly?

Comment: @lighthousekeeper I think I'd like something more like a whitelist than a filter, otherwise I would have to specify a filter for each conference name that I'm not interesed in. Also I don't have feedly pro, can I do that without pro?

Comment: I don't know that particular software, it was just my first idea. If the filter system is any good, it would allow you to specify a filter of the type "if the conference name is X or Y or Z, then stop processing; otherwise delete"